# Seeking Spinor Operation Analogous to $M^T \eta M = g$ for GL$^+(4,\mathbb{R})$/Spin$^c$(3,1)

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, group-theory, representation-theory, spinors

I'm exploring the spinorial representation of the Spin$^c$(3,1) group, especially in the context of metric preservation in general relativity and quantum field theory.

For the group GL$^+(4,\mathbb{R}$)/SO(3,1) acting on matrices, the metric-preserving condition under Lorentz transformations is given by $M^T \eta M = g$, where $M$ is a Lorentz transformation and $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric.

I'm interested in finding an analogous operation for spinors in the context of GL$^+(4,\mathbb{R})$/Spin$^c$(3,1). Specifically, I'm looking for an operation $\circ$ such that:
$$ \psi \circ \eta \psi = g $$
where $\psi$ is a spinor and $g$ is the resulting metric or bilinear form. But here $g$ may not be a metric; what I mean is that I am happy with $g$ containing additional structure to overshoot to SO(3,1) group to Spin$^c$(3,1): fermions and charge.

My questions are:

1. What is the operation $\circ$ on spinors that would yield a metric-preserving condition analogous to $M^T \eta M = g$?
2. How does this operation account for the additional $U(1)$ phase factor introduced by the $Spin^c$ structure?

Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.